# Sort by specific order in SolR

Tags: solr

I would like to sort my data by the "format", the order is 4002, 4009 and finally 999.

So this sort doesn't work : "sort = desc size".

Do you know how I can do ?

Regards,
Laurent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the three only values present, you can sort by a function query.

Or, you can abuse the `q` function to give different weights to each hit, and then have your actual queries in `fq` instead (since filter queries are non-scoring). I.e. `q=format:4002^10 format:4009^5 format:999^1`.

If you want to do it in a function query, you should be able to use a combination of `if` and `termfreq` functions to give sorting values for each term:

```
sort=if(termfreq(format,'4002'),1,if(termfreq(format,'4009'),2,if(termfreq(format,'999'),3,4))) asc
```